# Assemble P12 from local cert and HSM private key pointer?

Tags: openssl

I am using SoftHSM along with the OpenSSL PKCS11 library for the HSM and I can create certificates and sign so I know the interactivity is working.

I've created a certificate whose private key is stored on the HSM but I'd like to be able to create a .P12 file containing both the certificate's public key and the pointer for the HSM private key.

Does OpenSSL support this? The **OpenSSL PKCS12** command doesn't have a parameter for **-keyform** so I can't tell it to look at the engine for the key pointer. I've also tried to extract the pointer to a separate file by using **OpenSSL RSAUTL** but that doesn't work either.

Ultimately I'm trying to get to the same behavior you see when using certificates from smart cards...ie you can import them to your local user/machine store and it shows you have the private key (even though it's just a pointer).

Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

Highly doubt PKCS#12 supports that.

How do you expect the 'pointer' to behave? Some UUID that's recognized as existing on external HSM, and also identifying the HSM where it exists?